# Term for "wollen" in "er will das nicht gewusst haben"

Tags: terminology

If a sentence like *er will eine Beziehung/etwas kaufen/nichts* is the *desiderative* use of modal verbs, what would you call structures like *er will das nicht gewusst haben*?

Answer (score 5):

> (1) Er **soll** von nichts gewusst haben.
> (2) Er **will** von nichts gewusst haben.

*Sollen* and *wollen* in these examples can be called *berichtend*; in the literature, terms like *reportiv* and *quotativ* are used.<sup>*</sup>

In the reporting use of these verbs, *sollen* indicates that the source of knowledge is some third party, while *wollen* puts the subject as the source, as indicated by the following paraphrases.

> (1') **Es wird behauptet**, er habe von von nichts gewusst.
> (2') **Er behauptet**, er habe habe von nichts gewusst.

* <sup>See for instance the following work (which, although unfortunately not publicly accessible, allows searching the text for the aforementioned terms): Werner Abraham and Elisabeth Leiss (eds.), *Funktionen von Modalität*, https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110333091.</sup>